# Проблема с GetMem и памятью

Tags: массивы, delphi, память, динамические-массивы

Доброго времени суток!
У меня возникла проблема, которую я сам не могу решить вот уже несколько часов кряду. В программе используется процедура, которая "конвертирует" входящий `bitmap` в массив байт для более удобной работы с `bitmap`. Массив, естественно, динамический, и для задания его размера используется привычная `SetLength`. Однако я решил заменить `SetLength` на вызов `GetMem` с целью немного ускорить работу процедуры конвертации. Вот здесь и проблема.

Код ниже - "оригинальный", с использованием `SetLength`. Работает без нареканий.
Переменная `BmpArray` - это глобальная переменная модуля.

```
  type
    PQuadArray = ^TQuadArray;
    TQuadArray = Array [0..(MaxInt div SizeOf(TRGBQuad))-1] of TRGBQuad;
  ...
  var
    BmpArray: Array of PQuadArray;
  ...

  procedure ConvertBmpToBytes(const Bitmap: TBitmap);
  var
    BPP, BytesPerLine: Integer;
    X, Y: Integer;
    PPixels, PBytes: Pointer;
  begin
    BPP := SizeOf(TRGBQuad);

    SetLength(BmpArray, Bitmap.Width * Bitmap.Height * BPP);

    BytesPerLine := Bitmap.Width * BPP;
    for Y:=0 to Bitmap.Height - 1 do
      begin
        PBytes := @BmpArray[Y * BytesPerLine];
        PPixels := Bitmap.ScanLine[Y];
        CopyMemory(PBytes, PPixels, BytesPerLine);
      end;
  end;
```

Ниже приведен код, использующий `GetMem`. Заметьте, что тип массива изменился.

```
type
  PNewArray = ^NewArray;
  NewArray = Array [0..0] of PQuadArray;
var
  BmpArray: PNewArray;

  procedure ConvertBmpToBytes(const Bitmap: TBitmap);
  var
    BPP, BytesPerLine: Integer;
    X, Y: Integer;
    PPixels, PBytes: Pointer;
  begin
    BPP := SizeOf(TRGBQuad);

//    SetLength(BmpArray, Bitmap.Width * Bitmap.Height * BPP);
    GetMem(BmpArray, Bitmap.Width * Bitmap.Height * BPP);
    BytesPerLine := Bitmap.Width * BPP;
    for Y:=0 to Bitmap.Height - 1 do
      begin
        PBytes := @BmpArray[Y * BytesPerLine];
        PPixels := Bitmap.ScanLine[Y];
        CopyMemory(PBytes, PPixels, BytesPerLine);
      end;
  end;
```

Собственно, проблема в том, что вызов `CopyMemory` после определенного значения счетчика `Y` дает сбой - приложение "падает", `FastMM` иногда выдает сообщение вида

> FastMM has detected an error during a GetMem operation. The block header has been corrupted.

однако, это мне ни о чем не говорит - память под массив выделена корректно (или я ошибаюсь?), `ScanLine` входящего `bitmap` также корректен (предыдущий же код отрабатывает!).  В общем, прошу помощи, ибо возможно, где-то что-то я упустил.

*Заранее благодарю!*

**Важное дополнение к полученному ответу**
Благодаря ответу [участника Zed](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/177722/zed) я наконец-то понял, в чем изначально была причина проблемы с `GetMem`: в моем коде, в строке `@BmpArray[Y * BytesPerLine];` был выход за пределы массива, так как переменная `BytesPerLine` содержала помимо ширины `bitmap` также и количество байт на пиксель, что, безусловно, приводило к выходу за границы массива при последовательном чтении данных из входящего `bitmap`.

Вместе с тем, я не совсем понимаю, почему в первом варианте кода с применением `SetLength`, подобный выход за пределы массива не выливается в "падение" программы. Возможно, дело в том, каким именно образом `Delphi` внутренне работает с памятью для динамических массивов, но для более точного исследования мне не достает знаний.  В любом случае вывод один - быть предельно внимательным при программировании.

Comment: @AntonShchyrov, изменил вопрос, тип добавил.

Comment: Ваш код неработоспособный в принципе. Даже с массивами. То, что он у вас работает - чистая случайность. Опишите свою задачу? Зачем вы перегоняете пиксели в массив?

Comment: @AntonShchyrov, при всем уважении - Вы заблуждаетесь. Первый вариант кода (который использует `SetLength`), как я указал в самом вопросе - очень даже работоспособный. Со вторым вариантом (который `GetMem`) наблюдаются проблемы, характер которых мне непонятен. Вернее, понятно, что дело связано с память, но как именно связано? А перегоняю пиксели в массив для дальнейшей работы с ними (пискселями). Подобный подход значительно ускоряет работу с графикой в целом.

Comment: Антон, вероятно, имеет в виду, что в Вашем коде присутствует лишний слой указателей.

Comment: Вы объявляете `BmpArray` как массив указателей, соответственно, вам надо аллоцировать память под каждый элемент этого массива. И под `BmpArray` вы изначально выделяете больше места, чем требуется.

Comment: Лишний слой указателей, жесткая работа с 32-битным битмапом.

Comment: GetMem не даст прироста по сравнению с массивом. По крайней мере более 2-5%

Comment: Зачем вы перегоняете пиксели? Что вы хотите с ними делать?

Comment: @Igor, простите, но я не совсем понял что Вы имели ввиду под "лишний слой указателей".

Comment: @zed, даже если объявить `BmpArray` как массив записей `TRGBQuad`, это мне не помогло - программа по-прежнему крашится. По поводу размера массива: Высота * Ширина * Байт_На_Пиксель. Так как работа идет с 32-бит `bitmap`, то и байт на пиксель будет ровно 4. По-моему, все логично.

Comment: @AntonShchyrov, может прироста особого и не будет (необходимо точно проверить), но все-таки понять причину неработоспособности кода хотелось бы.

Comment: Т.е. у вас всегда работа с 32-битными битмапами. И с 24 вы работать не будете? Так?

Comment: @AntonShchyrov, безусловно. Прошу прощения, что сразу этого не указал в вопросе. Мне кажется, сейчас с 24-бит мало кто имеет дело.

Comment: Если вы объявите массив как `array of TRGBQuad`, то в коде вам всюду надо убрать умножение на `BPP` т.к. вы начинаете работать не с байтами, а с пикселями.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот так должно работать:

```
type
  PNewArray = ^TNewArray;
  TNewArray = array [0..0] of TRGBQuad;
var
  BmpArray: PNewArray;

  procedure ConvertBmpToBytes(const Bitmap: TBitmap);
  var    
    BPP, BytesPerLine: Integer;
    X, Y: Integer;
    PPixels, PBytes: Pointer;
  begin
    BPP := SizeOf(TRGBQuad);    
    GetMem(BmpArray, Bitmap.Width * Bitmap.Height * BPP);
    BytesPerLine := Bitmap.Width * BPP;
    for Y:=0 to Bitmap.Height - 1 do
      begin
        PBytes := @BmpArray[Y * Bitmap.Width];
        PPixels := Bitmap.ScanLine[Y];
        CopyMemory(PBytes, PPixels, BytesPerLine);
      end;
  end;
```

Тестовый код:

```
var
  b: TBitmap;
begin
  BmpArray := nil;
  b := TBitmap.Create;
  try
    b.PixelFormat := pf32bit;
    b.SetSize(10, 20);
    ConvertBmpToBytes(b);
    // ToDo: здесь надо освободить память BmpArray
  finally
    b.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Спасибо, но не работает. Не сочтите за дерзость, @zed, скомпилируйте код - будет видно, что он действительно на работает. И самое главное - непонятно почему.

Comment: @Dima А, точно, мой косяк - при выделении памяти надо указывать битность картинки. Выделяем-то мы байты.

Comment: Действительно, теперь работает! Видите, таки битность имеет значение)) Безусловно принимаю ответ. Кстати, причина моей первоначальной неудачи с `GetMem` была весьма простой, аж стыдно немного от того, что сам ее не нашел(( Если интересно - в  вопрос добавил пояснение.

Answer (score 3):

Вот вам правильный и работающий код с одномерным массивом

```
var
  BmpArray: array of TRGBQuad;
...

procedure ConvertBmpToBytes(const Bitmap: TBitmap);
const
  BPP := SizeOf(TRGBQuad);
var
  BytesPerLine: Integer;
  Y: Integer;
begin
  if Bitmap.PixelFormat <> pf32bit then
    raise Exception.Create('Unsupported pixel format');
  SetLength(BmpArray, Bitmap.Width * Bitmap.Height);
  BytesPerLine := Bitmap.Width * BPP;
  for Y:=0 to Bitmap.Height - 1 do begin
    Move(
      BmpArray[Y * BytesPerLine], 
      Bitmap.ScanLine[Y]^
      BytesPerLine
    );
  end;
end;
```

Вот вам правильный и работающий код с двумерным массивом

```
var
  BmpArray: array of array of TRGBQuad;
...

procedure ConvertBmpToBytes(const Bitmap: TBitmap);
const
  BPP := SizeOf(TRGBQuad);
var
  BytesPerLine: Integer;
  Y: Integer;
begin
  if Bitmap.PixelFormat <> pf32bit then
    raise Exception.Create('Unsupported pixel format');
  SetLength(BmpArray, Bitmap.Height, Bitmap.Width);
  BytesPerLine := Bitmap.Width * BPP;
  for Y:=0 to Bitmap.Height - 1 do begin
    Move(
      BmpArray[Y][0], 
      Bitmap.ScanLine[Y]^
      BytesPerLine
    );
  end;
end;
```

вот работа с `GetMem`

```
type
  PData = ^TData;
  TData = array[0..0] of TRGBQuad;
var
  BmpArray: PData;
...

procedure ConvertBmpToBytes(const Bitmap: TBitmap);
const
  BPP := SizeOf(TRGBQuad);
var
  BytesPerLine: Integer;
  Y: Integer;
begin
  if Bitmap.PixelFormat <> pf32bit then
    raise Exception.Create('Unsupported pixel format');
  GetMem(BmpArray, Bitmap.Height * Bitmap.Width * BPP);
  BytesPerLine := Bitmap.Width * BPP;
  for Y:=0 to Bitmap.Height - 1 do begin
    Move(
      BmpArray^[Y * BytesPerLine], 
      Bitmap.ScanLine[Y]^
      BytesPerLine
    );
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Хороший код, не спорю, но, код в ответе участника Zed делает то, что мне и нужно (в принципе, как и Ваш), однако, его ответ был отправлен немного раньше, поэтому я принял его ответ, но не Ваш. Тем не менее, "плюсанул" и закладку в браузере сделал. Спасибо!

Comment: @Dima а вот и зря. Правильным ответом отмечается правильный ответ, т.е. наиболее полезный, а не данный раньше.

Comment: @Kromster, ну почему же. Ответ участника Zed решил мою проблему, ответил на мой вопрос и появился раньше не менее ценного ответа участника Anton Shchyrov. Полагаю, мой выбор вполне обоснован.